# Understanding dependency inversion principle and creating a hardwired IOC container of my own for Dependency Injection without @Inject or @Autowired

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, solid-principles

I'm a little confused about the differences of the SOLID dependency Inversion principle and IOC containers. Should there only be one class responsible for wiring all the dependencies? I don't want to use a blackbox IOC container and wire these things up myself. I don't want to get distracted in the beginning with making a super generic one of my own. Hardwiring in just one place or class would do just great. Nor do I want to use any @Inject or @Autowired etc. That just hides the juicy details..

I want to understand how I would wire dependencies in one single place (a class or some properties file) and have the rest of the system not hardwired to specific implementations. I'm approaching it this to better understand how dependency inversion works and how its related to dependency injection.

So with that being said, how would I wire an EmployeeDAO interface for saving and deleting employees in a database or a filesystem or a nosql datastore? I'll be grateful for any examples for this usecase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you don't try to roll your own container.  Either use a container off the shelf, or don't use a container at all (it sounds like you want the latter).

```
public interface IEmployeeDAO
{
  void SaveEmployee(Employee employee);
}

public class ClassThatNeedsToSaveEmployees
{
  private readonly IEmployeeDAO _employeeDAO;

  public ClassThatNeedsToSaveEmployees(IEmployeeDAO employeeDAO)
  {
    _employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
  }
}
```

Now to instantiate the class, you need do something like this:

```
var myClass = new ClassThatNeedsToSaveEmployees(new EmployeeDAO());
```

Although it gets hairier as your dependencies have dependencies, e.g.:

```
var myClass = new ClassThatNeedsToSaveEmployees(new EmployeeDAO(new DatabaseConnectionFactory(new ConfigurationFileReader())));
```

In simple applications, this may not be a problem, but as your dependency graph grows, this becomes more difficult to maintain.  A container adds a bit of complexity to the setup of your application (and a bit of a learning curve), but it eases the pain of adding dependencies to your classes by having them automatically get injected, provided they are registered correctly.  So if your DatabaseConnectionFactory implementation needed an additional dependency of IWidget, you would just add an IWidget parameter to the constructor and it would automatically get injected.

Comment: Not my intention to spend time on writing a container. I just want to understand if i will have one class containing all the = new Blabla().

Comment: If you want to follow the practice that people use for containers, then yes, you will have one place at the entry point of your app with a giant "new MyClass()" statement that instantiates your root object and the whole graph of dependencies.  I would recommend you take a more pragmatic approach and instantiate these object graphs where it makes the most sense (and still support loose coupling and testability).

Comment: I think your confusing the association of concrete types with interfaces and instantiation. You wont have a very useful program if you have to instantiate every object at the beginning of the program.

Comment: If you want to mirror what a DI container does, this is what you need to do.  But even if you do it this way it's not *every* object, but the chain of dependencies in the object graph of services.  Also note that I'm not recommending this; I'm just answering the question.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand. See, I would never write an application like this, but what you mentioned but I'm trying to understand in simple terms what's really going on in java code